# Finding slope of lines using tangent and angles between them

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I previously asked a question about finding the center of a given dilation. As a follow up question I wanted to find the equations for the two lines tangent to the two circles. This is pretty vague, but my question is a bit more concrete.

Here's the setup. Suppose you are given the line described by $y = -\frac{x}{2} + \frac{11}{2}$, and that this lines lies between two lines, $T_1$ and $T_2$. These three lines intersect at $(1,5)$. The goal is to find equations for the two lines $T_1$, $T_2$. After a quick calculation, one sees that the angle formed by $l$ and $T_1$ is $\alpha = \arcsin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right)$, and the angle formed between $l$ and $T_2$ is also $\alpha$ (now sweeping clockwise). (So, the angle between $T_1$ and $T_2$ is $2\alpha$.) We can then find the slope of $T_1$ by adding to the slope of $l$ the value $\tan\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\right)$, giving $ -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = 0$. So the equation for $T_1$ is $y - 5 = 0$. Here is where my question comes.

When finding the slope of $T_2$ I took the slope of $T_1$ and added to it the value $\tan\left(-2\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\right)$, resulting in the value $0 - \frac{4}{3}$. So, $T_2$ has equation $y - 5 = -\frac{4}{3}(x - 1)$.

My question is, why can I not simply add the value $\tan\left(-\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\right)$ to the slope of $l$ to find the slope of $T_2$? I am assuming that it has to do with $\tan(a + b) \neq \tan(a) + \tan(b)$, but I'm not sure how to explain it.

Comment: You already have the answer and explained it nicely that $\tan(a+b)\ne \tan a+\tan b$.

Comment: I don't really understand why I can add tan of the angle $\alpha$ to the slope of $l$ to get the slope of $T_1$ but I cannot add tan of the angle $-\alpha$ to the slope of $l$ to get the slope of $T_2$. Why would it work for one, but not the other?

Comment: -@raynea, it is just an coincidence. For $T_1$ $\tan a\tan b=0$, so the result simplifies to $\tan\alpha=\frac{\tan a+\tan b}{1-0}$. But you can't generalise it.

Comment: Ah, so I realize now that I don't completely understand. I thought that adding $\tan \alpha$ to the slope of $l$ would always given the slope of the line, not necessarily as in this situation. This leads me to another question, how would you find the slopes of two lines given the angle formed between them (assuming the intersect)?

Comment: By the formula $\tan\theta=\bigg|\frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2}\bigg|$.

Comment: Nice! I am going to prove your formula. Thanks.